# Buscar un nombre de Imagen con File Exists en C#

Tags: c#

En mi base de datos tengo un campo que es el numero de guía, y ese mismo también es un nombre de imagen(`.jpg` o `.tif`). El tema, que tengo casos donde el número de guía tiene varias imágenes y en la carpeta de imágenes puedes figurar así:

```
nro_guia: GUIA00020---->> BASE DE DATOS
          GUIA00020__28042017165654.tif -------->>CARPETA DE IMAGENES
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para poder validar la existencia de la imagen de aquella guía?

```
               foreach (DataRow row in dtImagenes.Rows)
                {
                    string nom_imagen_db = 
                row["NroGuia"].ToString().TrimEnd(' ');
                    var ruta_imagen = Path.Combine(txt_ruta.Text, 
                nom_imagen_db + ".tif");
                    var ruta_imagen_2 = Path.Combine(txt_ruta.Text, 
                nom_imagen_db + ".jpg");

                    if (pgb_cargando.Value <= cantidad_imagen_db)
                    {
                        pgb_cargando.PerformStep();
                    }
                    if (!File.Exists(ruta_imagen) && 
                    !File.Exists(ruta_imagen_2)
                    {
                        string f_guia = row["FechaGuia"].ToString();
                        guias.InsertarGuiasValidadas(nom_imagen_db,
                        Convert.ToDateTime(f_guia),DateTime.Now, "NO");
                    }
                }
```

Este código funciona solo si el nombre de imagen es igual al de la guía.

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías buscar los archivos que cumplan con un patrón que inicie por el *nombre* de la guía. Si existe algún archivo, tiene imagen, por ejemplo algo en la línea de:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dtImagenes.Rows)
{
    string nom_imagen_db = row["NroGuia"].ToString().TrimEnd(' ');
    string[] archivos = Directory.GetFiles(txt_ruta.Text, nom_imagen_db + "_*.*");

    if archivos.Length > 0 {
      //si tiene guia
    }
}
```

Esto encontrará cualquier archivo que inicie con el nombre de la guía más un guión bajo `_`, pero igual encontrará archivos que no son imágenes. Ya lo puedes especializar si te interesa encontrar solamente las extensiones que mencionas. Seguro no es lo óptimo pues también recupera los nombres de los archivos y luego no los utiliza.